# String Codification - NodeJS addon; v8

Tags: node.js, v8

In Server Nodejs:

```
var random  = addon.function("random|random|João|Pinóquio");
```

As you can see I want to pass a string in latin codification.
In addon Nodejs:

```
void function(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
//(some code)
v8::String::Utf8Value param2(args[0]->ToString());
std::string wordlist = std::string(*param2); //JS---->C++
```

The utf-8 codification will cause problems in 'ã' 'ó' etc.etc. How can I change the codification?

One solution that I am discovered is:

```
v8::String::AsciiValue param1(args[0]->ToString());
```

But [AsciiValue](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1String_1_1AsciiValue.html#_details) (in my version) is not a member of class v8::String. Which is not normal since this member was created in 2011. I have version 0.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

Server:

```
var wordlist = new Buffer(all_the_string,'ascii');
var something = addon.function(wordlist,wordlist.length);
```

Addon:

```
int wordlist_length = args[1]->NumberValue();
Local<Object> algo = args[0]->ToObject();
const char* buf = node::Buffer::Data(algo);
std::string worlist_ascii;
worlist_ascii.assign(buf, wordlist_length);
```

Using the [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), the problem was solved.
AsciiValue is no longer used in nodejs after the version 0.12.0.